# Google Drive Javascript: How to Unzip All Files in A Folder

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am looking for a JS script which would unzip all files in a folder on Google Drive. I am the folder owner, I can get the folder IDs etc...

Typically, the folder would have few zipped files like this:

- Yesterday_Order_IDs_2016-10-11.zip
- Yesterday_Order_IDs_2016-10-12.zip
- Yesterday_Order_IDs_2016-10-13.zip
- ...

and so on. There would also previously unzipped files (csv).

**A few notes:**

1. It is possible that there would be no file to unzip when the script
   runs.
2. The unzipped files should be named the same as the original
   zip.
3. The unzipped files should be pasted into same folder.
4. Original zips should be deleted when the scripts finishes.

Comment: Are you using Apps Script, or is this within a browser? If the former consider [`Utilities.unzip`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzip(BlobSource))

Comment: if you are working from a browser you might like https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/

Comment: I want to everything via Apps Script... I will try Utilities.unzip from Bardy and ZIP Extractor from d.datul1990. Thx guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically extract zip file within Google drive by using ['ZIP Extractor'](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/examples/). Using ZIP Extractor you can choose which files in the zip file to extract after extracting the ZIP file, It can read ZIP files from Google Drive and extract their contents into Google Drive.

Link below is a demo app for ZIP Extractor: https://github.com/googledrive/zipextractor